# In Rust, why does size_of_val() for a 10 character string return 24 bytes?

Tags: rust

In Rust:

```rust
println!("{}", mem::size_of_val(&String::from("1234567890")));
```

Prints `24`.

I understand `String` may store additional data, eg, the length of the string, But where do the 24 bytes come from?

```rust
use std::mem;

fn main() {
    println!("{}", mem::size_of_val(&String::from("1234567890")));
    return ()
}
```

My architecture is arm64 if it's relevant.

Comment: Don't take this the wrong way, but I suggest you read the Rust book. All this stuff is explained very well there.

Comment: Looking through the Rust Book, Strings aren't covered until Chapter 8, well beyond the first use of strings. See https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch08-02-strings.html.

Comment: @mikemaccana indeed, but the advice is probably to read the *whole* book. It contains only essential information for day-to-day Rust programming (even though it might look like it at first), so you *will* need that information anyways.

Comment: I do understand the book is a valuable resource, but It seems very odd to not cover a basic topic like strings until far after they're first used.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A `String` in Rust has a size of 24 bytes, because it is composed of a pointer (8 bytes on 64bit systems) to the heap, a 8 byte length, and a 8 byte capacity.

A `String` doesn’t store the data inline, as it stores the bytes of the value on the heap. If you want the length of the underlying bytes, use `String::len`.

[The documentation regarding a `String`s representation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#representation)

Comment: I’ve updated my comment to include the link to the documentation. “capacity” is the maximum number of elements that can be added to a heap-allocated structure (like `String` or `Vec<T>`) before a reallocation is necessary

Comment: Thanks, I saw the reference also mentions what capacity was. I just had to wait 2 minutes to accept the answer!

Comment: *Actually* [insert meme] a `std::string::String` in Rust only stores a `Vec<u8>` which in turn stores a `RawVec` and a `usize`. `RawVec` in turn stores a unique pointer, a capacity via a `usize` and an allocator.